# Legend to D3.js scatterplot

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have created a scatter chart with multiple y-axis. 
I need to create a legend to indicate the scattering.
I have created a fiddle of the same in the link provided in comments.
Please help me out.

Comment: Link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/amithraj/y3LEt/1/

Comment: It looks like you've already attempted to add a legend. What specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: The legend is not appearing in the graph and I do not know how do I proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in your code colors is an object, not an array.

D3 expects the data that is passed to it to be an array:

I've updated your fiddle - see http://jsfiddle.net/y3LEt/3/

The critical updates are:

```
var colors =    [["Local", "#377EB8"],
                    ["Global", "#4DAF4A"]];

legendRect
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
        return i * 20;
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return d[1];
    });
```

Comment: Thank You for your time. could you by any chance have any idea of making it interactive?